# How to get particular model in backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

As i made a collection of Users in backbone , I added few users in users collection and it is added.now i want to remove the a particular user from my collection with particular username.

So what i have done is i made a method in my collection :

```
user: function(username) {
    return this.filter(function(user){ return user.get('username')==username; });
  }
```

and then i access it like this :

```
App.Users.user(data.username);
```

then for removing a particular element i do :

```
App.Users.remove(App.Users.user(data.user));
```

and for updating the user data i do :

```
App.Users.user(data.username)[0].set(data)
```

Please check my code , and suggest if i can improve it any ways .

Comment: i have few clarifications here,

1)App.Users.user(data.username); should be 
  
  var cltn = new App.Users({
    user:function(){
      as you defined.
    }
  }) ; 
  cltn.user(data.username);


2)if you have done that correctly then, cltn.remove(cltn.user(data.user)); should be 
   

  cltn.remove(cltn.user(data.username));

Comment: the above is working but i want to know that it is proper way of doing or not

Comment: i have done it by passing the `id` property in model and then accessing model by `get` method.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of App.Users, use App.Models.Users. This will increase readability. Everything else seems fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

If a username is unique, then you should use this.detect() instead of this.filter().  It would be slightly faster and also I believe also returns a single model instead of an array...

If the username isn't unique, ignore this...

Also, you should use '===' instead of '=='.

Comment: i have done it by passing the id property in model and then accessing model by get method. is n't it good ?

Comment: I was talking about your 'user' function where you are finding the user based on the username.